# Custom event args on a dynamically assigned event handler

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates

I am assigning a click event handler like so

```
var buttonEvent = button.GetType().GetEvent("Click");
var eventMethod = GetType().GetMethod("button_Click");

var handler = Delegate.CreateDelegate(buttonEvent.EventHandlerType, this, eventMethod);

buttonEvent.AddEventHandler(button, handler);
```

The click event handler is like so:

```
void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
```

**How can I pass custom args into the handler?** Ideally I would love

```
void button_Click(object sender, MyCustomEventArgs e) { }
```

where I can set MyCustomEventArgs when I assign the event.

Comment: did you learn inheritance?

Comment: I understand `MyCustomEventArgs` will extend `EventArgs`. I just don't get where/how to put anything in it

Comment: in your `MyCustomButton` which extends `Button`, override the onClick method

Comment: not really feasible. there must be another way, and that still doesn't explain how I populate MyCustomEventArgs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plain and simple, you can't.

The `Button` class invokes that event, and when it invokes it, it populates the arguments. In this case, with an `EventArgs` object (no custom data allowed).

This holds true for *any* event. Unless the class raising the event supports some way of inserting custom data into the event stream, you can't control what it gives you via the event handler.

Note that there *is* one clever trick for UI event handlers. Because the sending object is held in "sender" and you can put *anything* in the "Tag" property, you can have custom data in your event by doing:

```
control.Tag = someObject;
control.Click += (o, e) =>
{
     Control c = o as Control;
     MyObject data = c.Tag as MyObject;
     //use data
};
```

Also, in WPF, you can do this with `CommandParameter` since that is also a generic object. Of course, thats not event handlers, but its still the same general idea.